# Padding-top of div inside div

Tags: css

I have really weird problem. I want to do rectangle in rectangle, but dont know why, i cant set padding-top of inside-rectangle. Can somebody tell my why?

```css
#outsideRect{
    width: 260px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #4084dd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#insideRect{
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="page">
        <div id="outsideRect">
            <div id="insideRect">
                as
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#outsideRect{
    width: 160px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #4084dd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#insideRect{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.page { display: inline-block; }

#outsideRect2{
    width: 160px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #4084dd;
    border-radius: 10px;
   padding-top: 20px;
}
#insideRect2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#outsideRect3{
    width: 160px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #4084dd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#insideRect3{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   padding-top: 20px;
}


#insideRect4{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}


#insideRect5{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div  class="page">
        <div id="outsideRect">
            <div id="insideRect">
                margin on inner rect
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div  class="page">
        <div id="outsideRect2">
            <div id="insideRect2">
               padding on outer rect
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

   <div  class="page">
        <div id="outsideRect3">
            <div id="insideRect3">
               padding on inner rect
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



   <div  class="page">
        <div id="outsideRect">
            <div id="insideRect4">
               margin on inner rect
            </div>
          
          
            <div id="insideRect5">
              no margin or padding on inner rect
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Padding is always **inside** the element. Margin is *outside* the element.

You want to add padding to the *outer* rectangle if you want the inner rectangle to move down.

Or do you mean to ask why your margin on the inner rectangle isn't working? It's applied outside... between block level elements.  Since the inner rectangle is a child of the Outer rectangle, the margin doesn't get allied between parent/child. It get applied between parents. Note how in the 4th example in the snippet the margin is applied to other elements at the same level, but it does not get applied between the parent/child.

Comment: YAS, thats solution :) But why it dosent works with declared "padding-top" in insideRect?

Comment: Because padding is *inside* the element. So adding `padding-top` to the inner rectangle moves the "as" inside it down.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#outsideRect{
    width: 260px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #4084dd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#insideRect{
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
  padding-top: 30px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="page">
        <div id="outsideRect">
            <div id="insideRect">
                as
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The padding in the solution can be added without any problem in your solution.

As Scott has mentioned, margin is outside of the element, and padding is inside of the element.

If you want to use the margin in the solution, you will need to add position.

For example:

```css
#outsideRect{
    width: 260px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #4084dd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#insideRect{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="page">
        <div id="outsideRect">
            <div id="insideRect">
                as
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```